# Castle.Windsor and dynamic injection using calling method parameters values

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a class library:

```
 public class SomeBL : ISomeBL
 {
    private IUser myUser;
    public SomeBL(IUser user)
    {
      myUser = user;
    }
    public void TestMethod()
    {
       ...some code using the user...
    }
 }
```

I also have a factory in this code library:

```
public class BLFactory
{
    public static ISomeBL SomeBL
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISomeBL>(); }
    }
}
```

Then I have a separate wcf application with one service that looks like this:

```
public class MyWcfService : IMyWcfService
{
       public void TestMethod(User user)
       {
            BLFactory.SomeBL.TestMethod();
       }
}
```

As you can see I am in need of IoC to properly resolve the IUser property on the SomeBL constructor level. I also don't want to pass it explicitly.

I was wondering if it's possible to configure Windsor in such a way that IUser will be resolved dynamically using value from the wcf service method's parameter ?

p.s.
Let's forget about wcf's inability to pass interfaces for a moment.

Edit#1
I solved it using Castle Project's Wcf Facility. Smooth as silk after I added it!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the way you have things set up, and with your conditions I don't see how it's possible.  There is no way for the container to "just know" the context by configuration.

However, I see a few options.

The first is to make your BLFactory a proper abstract factory, and pass the user to its Create method:

```
public class BLFactory  
{  
    public ISomeBL Create(IUser user)
    {              
        return new SomeBL(user);   
    }  
}
```

You could also do this by calling Resolve<>() and passing the parameter there, or using Windsor's Typed Factory Facility.  Referencing the container to directly resolve service in a factory class is generally not a good practice (see [Three Calls Pattern](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Three-Calls-Pattern.ashx)).

Second option would be to pass the user as a method parameter (although you said you don't want to do this):

```
 public class SomeBL : ISomeBL        
 {        
    public void TestMethod(IUser user)        
    {        
       ...some code using the user...        
    }        
 }
```

This makes SomeBL more of a pure service (stateless), which IMHO is more along the lines of what DI and Windsor should be used for.

A final option assumes that the user represents the logged in user (if this is incorrect, ignore this option).  Look at creating a service that returns the current logged-in user and inject that servce into your class.  You would use some form of [Ambient Context](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/07/23/ambientcontext.aspx) to store the user (on login or at some other point) and retrieve the user via this service.

```
 public class SomeBL : ISomeBL               
 {               
    private IUser _userservice;               
    public SomeBL(IUserService userservice)               
    {               
      _userservice = userservice;               
    }               
    public void TestMethod()               
    {               
       IUser currentUser = _userService.GetCurrentUser();
    }
 }

 public interface IUserService
 {
   IUser GetCurrentUser();
 }

 public class UserService : IUserService
 {
   public IUser GetCurrentUser
   {
      //pull user from Thread, HttpContext.CurrentRequest, cache, session, etc.
   }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I know it's kind of possible, it's just the "take-user-from-calling-method" part that I don't even know how to start with. To follow your assumption with the user, here's how I could do it with passing a current user from some session helper: container.Register(Component.For<IUser>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => SessionHelper.CurrentIUser).LifeStyle.Transient );

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by the use of Typed Factory see http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Typed-Factory-Facility-interface-based-factories.ashx